# Unable to deduce type parameters in global function

Tags: python, c++, templates, cython

I’m trying to wrap a heavily templatized C++ library that uses classes and global functions acting on them.

I would like to know why, in the following example, the Cython compiler gives me the error “Unable to deduce type parameters” in `get(c, 1)` whereas I get no complaints about the line preceding it:

```
cdef extern from "file.h":
  cdef cppclass Container[T]:
    pass

  T get_first[T](Container[T])
  T get[T](Container[T], size_t)

cdef Container[int] c
get_first(c)
get(c, 1)
```

The contents of `file.h` are not relevant since the message is emitted by the Cython compiler, which does not look at the file (it only generates an `#include` statement for it). The problem can be reproduced without even the file existing.

*This question has also been posted to the Cython users mailing list on July 1st.*

Comment: If that depends on the C++ code, your question is incomplete, because it's supposed to contain a minimal but complete example.

Comment: It does not depend on the C++ code. I edited the question to make this clear.

Comment: Which is the line that gets the error?

Comment: @Scooter good point, added

Comment: Not really an answer (so not posted as such) but: I suspect it's a limitation in Cython. If you want to work round it you can always call `get[int](c,1)` to tell it explicitly, but it isn't obvious why it's failed.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, I hadn’t thought of that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Cython.

Cython is unable to deduce the type parameters for that function call 
because the type of the second argument is different (`size_t` vs `long`). 
It should implicitly convert the argument as C++ does while searching for (templated) overloads, but it aborts template deduction when the type of the 
non-template `size_t` argument doesn't match.

To make the template deduction succeed, you can write `get(c, <size_t>1)` (or store the second argument in a variable of type `size_t` before passing it to `get()`).

To specify the desired template yourself and skip template deduction entirely, you can do as [DavidW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4657412/davidw) said and write `get[int](c, 1)`

I've posted the technical details to the Cython users mailing list.

Comment: Note that as far as Cython is concerned, `size_t` and `long` are always different types. It doesn't know, nor care, what base C type `size_t` is defined as - it simply ranks `size_t` as longer than `long` and shorter than `long long`

Answer (score 4):

This bug has been fixed in recent cython versions. The code above can be compiled without problems at least since Cython 0.25.2 .